# How to "Reset" the UDF DETERMINISTIC reponses?

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

IN DB2 V5R4, When you modify the functionality of a DETERMINISTIC UDF It returns the cached response for a while...

There are any way to reset the cached responses?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reset it how?  If it _needs_ to be reset, that would imply that the results aren't deterministic _on the values passed in_ - which is what I would assume **ALL** RDBMSs would base their optimization off of.  You may need to make the UDF non-deterministic, or see about splitting up the function into determinisitic and non-deterministic parts.  Can you give us the larger context?  We may be able to help.

Comment: Modifiying the funcionality of a Deterministic UDF it returns for a while the answer of the previous behavior. (V5R4 Did't implement ALTER FUNCTION statement, you MUST first DROP and then CREATE again the function...)

Comment: Ah, I didn't quite get that it'd been modified - I thought you were wanting to reset it during a statement run...  I don't know about any specific command - I would have thought that the `DROP` and `CREATE` cleared any cache.  IPLing the system would (almost certainly) do it, but be a bit heavy-handed; perhaps check with your IBM rep?

Comment: I will.... Thanks X-Zero

Comment: If you solve the problem try to give us a solution.

Comment: Flush package cache probably does this. However, there doesn't seem to be public documentation available on the matter.

Comment: If you recycle the database (force all connections) then the function has to be re-executed, thus the cache will be reseted.

Answer (score 0):

To what is it returning the cached response? Is it through a remote connection or a native access? You might try closing and re-opening any remote connection, or ending and restarting any local jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. Temporarily create the function *not deterministic*, do your testing. When everything is fine replace the function *deterministic*.